# How to fix a winload.exe error on a grub2 multiboot system after partition resizing?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, resize

I had a working win7, win10 and Linux multi-boot system before resizing the win10 partition to give more space to win7.

When it was done resizing and restarted, it only gave some kind of light blue/your PC needs to be fixed "winload.exe" error, it should have loaded up grub2 first?

I already tried the /fixboot and /rebuild commands, but /fixboot gave "access denied" error and /rebuild /scans only found 1 os from the system(win7), so i did not add it to the list

it shows all of the windows os-es/volumes in the repair disk's troubleshooting options

so i wonder what part of it actually failed and can i fix it by reinstalling grub2 or  or does the windows 10 partition/winload.exe still need to be fixed

it does load up only win7 system when i press the F9 key on that light blue error screen... (F8 and Enter just goes in a loop and won't do anything in there...) - and when i check the startup options under msconfig, it shows that the win10 partition is default, but just doesn't show any drive letter in front of it (which might be quite normal for a multi-boot system tho?)

Comment: Imagine you shank Windows partition from Ubuntu, that is usually a bad idea.  Will need to fix Win 10 from/with Windows tools.  Do not try to use Linux/Ubuntu to fix Windows.  Windows has repair tools on OS and I think on the USB installer.

Comment: ok, maybe i can try win7 repair disk then, because that actually seems to have some better automatic repair tools? or win10 automatic startup repair might fix something too?

Comment: altho win10 repair probably asked for a target op-sys, but is that the last one aka the same win10, in a multiboot system then?